# Is there a way to streamline a random.randint script?

Tags: python, list, random

I am creating a game where a user must guess a song, I have implemented a notepad document containing a list of popular songs. I have randomised the selection of a song using this

```
CurrentSong = random.randint(0,39) 
if CurrentSong == 0: 
    CurrentSong = Song[0]
elif CurrentSong == 1:
    CurrentSong = Song[1]

(this repeats for 40 songs)
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this in a shorter/more efficient way?

The actual code.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to post code or error message unless the image is conveying something more than the code or error message. If you need to you should augment the image with the text it contains because images of text are not searchable, accessible, and they make it harder for people trying to help you. Please read also [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

```
CurrentSong = random.choice(Song)
```

Read more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences)

Answer (score 2):

RichieV's answer is the most Pythonic way to pick a random thing from a list.

But, it doesn't answer the spirit of your question.

You shouldn't have a chain of ifs. You should use the variable to index your list.

This is going to look confusing because you are re-using and misusing your `CuSong` variable to hold the index number at the top, and later to hold the result of looking up the value in the list. Eeek.

To do what you did, it's be just

```
CuSong = Song[CuSong]
```

But, don't do that. Store the number in a different variable, and use it to index into the list.

```
song_number = from_somewhere()
chosen_song = songs[song_number]
```

Also, don't make variables capital. That is reserved style for python classes. It will confuse your readers.

Comment: Thankyou, I have been acquainted with Python for a while but have recently been doing some "challenging" projects, I appreciate your help.